# Cannot access Azure API App. Swagger doc is working fine in the Azure Web Portal

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api2, azure-web-app-service, swagger

After having published my Azure API App through Visual Studio 2013, I cannot access any of my REST endpoints. (The Azure Web Portal shows the swagger doc though). [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6eCy.png).

When going to the API App URL, I get the following page, with this error message:

> Correlation ID: b2228863-3f90-4235-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx
>
> Timestamp: 2015-04-06 07:48:59Z
>
> AADSTS50011: **The reply address
>   'https://microsoft-apiapp497f3b72e6ef485189341ae1ea31bddb.azurewebsites.net/'
>   does not match the reply addresses configured for the application:
>   abfa0a7c-a6b6-4736-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx.**

I have tried re-creating the API App several times, and tried republishing. The API App Access Level is set to Public (anonymous), so it should be exposed for everyone without logging in. I tried to configure it with Azure AD authentication, but it also didn't work.

Comment: well this isn't really possible to answer since you blacked out the relevant information in your screenshot, but is that a typo with the space in 'h ttps://...' ?

Comment: Which information do you need @Claies? No it is not a typo, it is because my reputation was too low to have more links than 2 in my post. The 'reply address' link from the error message, points to my Azure Api App URL.

Comment: the error is very clear, the reply address in your app doesn't match the one you supplied when you configured the app.  the first thing that stands out is the odd space there in the `h ttps://` in that error you posted.

Comment: ah, so then this goes back to seeing the full reply address and seeing what you configured the application with, and comparing them character for character.

Comment: When i click on the Api APP URL in the Azure Web Portal https://microsoft-apiapp497f3b72e6ef485189341ae1ea31bddb.azurewebsites.net/ i get this error. The url and the reply address is the same. I didn't configure this anywhere, it was set automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error appears to be related to App Insight.  Microsoft is aware of the issue and working on a fix, according to the post on 4/3/2015.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/96eeb06c-8157-4a4f-9d3a-4fa3eced5c55/authentication-failure-on-new-api-app-even-though-authentication-is-disabled?forum=AzureAPIApps.

Unchecking Azure Insights in the project options should allow you to use the API for testing.

Comment: Thanks, i can confirm that removing App Insights nuget packages from the project, and republishing the project will make it work. I can see that i am not the only one who spent 2 days figuring this out. :)

Comment: glad it was something straightforward